# How to pass a user defined argument in scrapy spider

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to pass a user defined argument to a scrapy's spider. Can anyone suggest on how to do that?

I read about a parameter `-a` somewhere but have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 240, accepted):

Spider arguments are passed in the `crawl` command using the `-a` option. For example:

```
scrapy crawl myspider -a category=electronics -a domain=system
```

Spiders can access arguments as attributes:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    def __init__(self, category='', **kwargs):
        self.start_urls = [f'http://www.example.com/{category}']  # py36
        super().__init__(**kwargs)  # python3

    def parse(self, response)
        self.log(self.domain)  # system
```

Taken from the Scrapy doc: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments

**Update 2013**: Add second argument

**Update 2015**: Adjust wording

**Update 2016**: Use newer base class and add super, thanks @Birla

**Update 2017**: Use Python3 super

```
# previously
super(MySpider, self).__init__(**kwargs)  # python2
```

**Update 2018**: [As @eLRuLL points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41123138/858913), spiders can access arguments as attributes

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer.

But lets say I want to pass two arguments, would I use something like:

scrapy crawl myspider -a category=electronics domain=system

or 

scrapy crawl myspider -a category=electronics -a domain=system

Comment: scrapy crawl myspider -a category=electronics -a domain=system

Comment: The above code is only partially working for me. For eg. If I define domain using `self.domain`, I'm still not able to access it outside the `__init__` method. Python throws a not defined error.  BTW, why have you omitted the `super` call? PS. I'm working with the CrawlSpider class

Comment: Is it possible for me to call the same spider multiple times concurrently since i have got an argument @Siddharth

Comment: @FlyingAtom Please correct me if I misunderstood, but each of these concurrent calls would be different instances of the the spider, wouldn't it ?

Comment: @Birla, use self.domain=domain in constructor to populate class scope variable.

Comment: This seems both overkill and not robust. The __init__ class is optional. The `print getattr(self,'category', '')` from Hassan Raza is simpler and more robust and flexible.

Comment: @nealmcb `__init__` is a _method_ of the spider class. Its implementation does does not itself make the spider any less robust and it is included in the answer to show that you can declare defaults for keyword arguments but as you said it's optional. As we pointed out last year you don't need to use `getattr` you can just access arguments as attributes, e.g `self.category` or as we see in the answer `self.domain`

Comment: Thanks! And oops - sorry about my silly "init class" typo.... I'm still unclear on what would happen if `domain` was not defined on the command line. Is there a default of None for all attributes? I suggest documenting that in the answer. It is nice to be able to incorporate the `category` in the `start_urls`. But otherwise, so far it seems preferable to me to use `getattr` with a default, which seems clearer and more concise.

Answer (score 57):

Previous answers were correct, but you don't have to declare the constructor (`__init__`) every time you want to code a scrapy's spider, you could just specify the parameters as before:

```
scrapy crawl myspider -a parameter1=value1 -a parameter2=value2
```

and in your spider code you can just use them as spider arguments:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'myspider'
    ...
    def parse(self, response):
        ...
        if self.parameter1 == value1:
            # this is True

        # or also
        if getattr(self, parameter2) == value2:
            # this is also True
```

And it just works.

Answer (score 21):

To pass arguments with crawl command

> scrapy crawl myspider -a category='mycategory' -a domain='example.com'

To pass arguments to run on scrapyd replace **-a** with **-d**

> curl http://your.ip.address.here:port/schedule.json -d 
>    spider=myspider -d category='mycategory' -d domain='example.com'

The spider will receive arguments in its constructor.

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name="myspider"
    def __init__(self,category='',domain='', *args,**kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.category = category
        self.domain = domain
```

Scrapy puts all the arguments as spider attributes and you can skip the **init** method completely. Beware use **getattr** method for getting those attributes so your code does not break.

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name="myspider"
    start_urls = ('https://httpbin.org/ip',)

    def parse(self,response):
        print getattr(self,'category','')
        print getattr(self,'domain','')
```

Answer (score 11):

Spider arguments are passed while running the crawl command using the -a option. For example if i want to pass a domain name as argument to my spider then i will do this-

> scrapy crawl myspider -a domain="http://www.example.com"

And receive arguments in spider's constructors:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'myspider'
    def __init__(self, domain='', *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_urls = [domain]
        #
```

...

it will work :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively we can use [ScrapyD](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which expose an API where we can pass the start_url and spider name. ScrapyD has api's to stop/start/status/list the spiders.

```
pip install scrapyd scrapyd-deploy
scrapyd
scrapyd-deploy local -p default
```

`scrapyd-deploy` will deploy the spider in the form of egg into the daemon and even it maintains the version of the spider. While starting the spider you can mention which version of spider to use.

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    def __init__(self, start_urls, *args, **kwargs):
        self.start_urls = start_urls.split('|')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    name = testspider
```

`curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=default -d spider=testspider -d start_urls="https://www.anyurl...|https://www.anyurl2"`

Added advantage is you can build your own UI to accept the url and other params from the user and schedule a task using the above scrapyd schedule API

Refer [scrapyd API documentation](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schedule-json) for more details