# Pass Scrapy Spider a list of URLs to crawl via .txt file

Tags: python, web-scraping, command-line-arguments, scrapy

I'm a little new to Python and very new to Scrapy.

I've set up a spider to crawl and extract all the information I need.  However, I need to pass a .txt file of URLs to the start_urls variable.

For exmaple:

```
class LinkChecker(BaseSpider):
    name = 'linkchecker'
    start_urls = [] #Here I want the list to start crawling a list of urls from a text file a pass via the command line.
```

I've done a little bit of research and keep coming up empty handed.  I've seen this type of example ([How to pass a user defined argument in scrapy spider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611605/how-to-pass-a-user-defined-argument-in-scrapy-spider)), but I don't think that will work for a passing a text file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Run your spider with `-a` option like:

```
scrapy crawl myspider -a filename=text.txt
```

Then read the file in the `__init__` method of the spider and define `start_urls`:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'myspider'

    def __init__(self, filename=None):
        if filename:
            with open(filename, 'r') as f:
                self.start_urls = f.readlines()
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

you could simply read-in the .txt file:

```
with open('your_file.txt') as f:
    start_urls = f.readlines()
```

if you end up with trailing newline characters, try:

```
with open('your_file.txt') as f:
    start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

If your urls are line seperated

```
def get_urls(filename):
        f = open(filename).read().split()
        urls = []
        for i in f:
                urls.append(i)
        return urls
```

then this lines of code will give you the urls.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'nameofspider'

    def __init__(self, filename=None):
        if filename:
            with open('your_file.txt') as f:
                self.start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
```

This will be your code. It will pick up the urls from the .txt file if they are separated by lines, like,
url1
url2
etc..

After this run the command -->

```
scrapy crawl nameofspider -a filename=filename.txt
```

Lets say, your filename is 'file.txt', then, run the command -->

```
scrapy crawl myspider -a filename=file.txt
```