# Is it possible to make a function that generates CrawlSpider, based on the URL provided by a user?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

is it possible to make a CrawlSpider after taking url input from a user? normally when we are creating a spider we physically give or specify a certain url. Is it possible to take an url from a user, and create a crawlspider based on that url?

Comment: Probably.  I doubt that CrawlSpider cares where you got the url from ... Do you have some example code for how you would create one without user input (i.e. "specifying a certain url")?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611605/how-to-pass-a-user-defined-argument-in-scrapy-spider  or http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments and adapt to CrawlSpider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can write a scrapy spider in a single python file and then write another python file to do those operations:

- receive the url that user input
- execute the spider with url arguments like that you execute a system command in a python file

Something like this:
You have a scrapy spider named **myspider.py** and a control script named **controlspider.py** (refer to this [doc](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-run-a-spider-without-creating-a-project) to learn how to run a scrapy spider in a signle file).
In **controlspider.py**, you could run the spider with urls that user has input like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['scrapy', 'runspider', 'myspider.py', 'URL_LIST_USER_INPUT'])
```

Then in **myspider.py**, you could receive the arguments in a subclass of CrawlSpider like this:

```
import sys
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    def __init__(self):
        ......
        # store the urls that you pass to the spider in 'controlspider.py'
        self.urls = sys.argv
```

The solution seems not elegant. In my opinion, if the logic of your crawl task is not so complex that you have to use **scrapy**, you could just write a small spider that could receive urls, crawl the page, parse the page and store the results. This will be very flexible and not so hard to implement.