# Python Scrapy - Scraping data from multiple website URLs

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

For one of my web project I need to scrape data from different web sources. To keep it simple i am explaining with an example.

Lets say i want to scrape the data about mobiles listed in their manufacturer site.

http://www.somebrand1.com/mobiles/
.
.
http://www.somebrand3.com/phones/

I have huge list of URLs.
Every brand's page will have their own way of HTML presentation for browser.

How can i write a normalized script to traverse the HTML of those listing web page URLs and scrape the data irrespective of the format they are in?

Or else do i need to write a script to scrape data from every pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a *Broad Crawling* and, generally speaking, this is not an easy thing to implement because of the different nature, representation, loading mechanisms web-sites use.

The general idea would be to have a generic spider and some sort of a site-specific configuration where you would have a mapping between item fields and xpath expressions or CSS selectors used to retrieve the field values from the page. In a real life, things are not that simple as it seems, some fields would require post-processing, other fields would need to be extracted after sending a separate request etc. In other words, it would be *very difficult to keep generic and reliable at the same time*.

The generic spider should receive a target site *[as a parameter](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/broad-crawls.html%20%20%20[1]:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611605/how-to-pass-a-user-defined-argument-in-scrapy-spider)*, read the site-specific configuration and crawl the site according to it.

Also see:

- [Broad Crawls](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/broad-crawls.html%20%20%20[1]:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611605/how-to-pass-a-user-defined-argument-in-scrapy-spider)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. And is there an anyway that i could minimize the process time. Provided a huge list, what would be the effective way?

Comment: @Bubi you are welcome. Do you mean you have a huge list of web-sites you want to crawl?

Comment: Yes. I meant that. I have a big list of domains to crawl.

Comment: @Bubi yeah, got it. I'd keep your domains in the database. Then, separately, go through your urls one-by-one and create field annotations and save them in the database per-domain. In the spider, read the domains from the database and start requests. It's difficult to help without knowing the specifics. Hope, at least, things are more clear now.

Comment: Yes this seems to be good one. Will give a try. Thank you for the suggestion!