# How to pass multiple arguments to Scrapy spider (getting error running 'scrapy crawl' with more than one spider is no longer supported)?

Tags: python, scrapy

I would like to pass multiple user-defined arguments to my scrapy spyder, so I tried to follow this post: [How to pass a user defined argument in scrapy spider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611605/how-to-pass-a-user-defined-argument-in-scrapy-spider)

However, when I follow the advice there I get an error:

```
root@ scrapy crawl dmoz -a address= 40-18 48th st -a borough=4
Usage
=====
  scrapy crawl [options] <spider>

crawl: error: running 'scrapy crawl' with more than one spider is no longer supported
```

I also tried with various permutations of quotation marks:

```
root@ scrapy crawl dmoz -a address= "40-18 48th st" -a borough="4"
Usage
=====
  scrapy crawl [options] <spider>
crawl: error: running 'scrapy crawl' with more than one spider is no longer supported
```

What is the correct way to pass parameters to the Scrapy spider? I would like to pass a username and password for the spider's login/scraping process. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No `scrapy` problem, I guess. It's how your `shell` interprets input, spliting tokens in spaces. So, you must not have any of them between the key and its value. Try with:

```
scrapy crawl dmoz -a address="40-18 48th st" -a borough="4"
```

Comment: I did try that option as well. I am using Ubuntu in case that matters, but I have tried every permutation of quotation marks on the input and names of the inputs. Unless I am missing something, what you suggested is exactly what I have at the end of my question as an example of what I have already tried?

Comment: @sunny: Sure you tried my solution and didn't work either? It's different. The `-a` switch accepts a `key=value` argument, but the shell process the input before `scrapy`, and the space after  the `=` sign makes it to generate two different tokens, that `scrapy` interprets as another spider.

Comment: I just copied and pasted your line, and it gave me the exact same error as what I've pasted above.

Comment: @sunny: Then, sorry. I had tested yours with same error, and mine with success, so I cannot help much more because cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: thanks a lot. I really appreciate your help. I'll try rebooting, but that doesn't generally matter on Linux. I think you're right it must be a shell issue, so I'll point my inquiries that way.

Comment: I'm sorry I was totally wrong. Once I restarted everything was fine. Maybe it was something to do with my putty connection or I don't know? Your solution is working now.