# Scraping items using scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler, scrapy

I have written the following spider for scraping the webmd site for patient reviews

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "webmd"
    allowed_domains = ["webmd.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.webmd.com/drugs/drugreview-92884-Boniva"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//p")
        title = titles.select("//p[contains(@class, 'comment')and contains(@style, 'display:none')]/text()").extract()
        print(title)
```

Executing this code gives me desired output but with a lot of duplication i.e. the same comments are repeated for at least 10 times.
Help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite your spider code like this:

```
import scrapy

# Your Items 
class ReviewItem(scrapy.Item):
    review = scrapy.Field()


class WebmdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "webmd"
    allowed_domains = ["webmd.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.webmd.com/drugs/drugreview-92884-Boniva']

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.xpath('//p[contains(@id, "Full")]')
        for title in titles:
            item = ReviewItem()
            item['review'] = title.xpath('text()').extract_first()
            yield item

        # Checks if there is a next page link, and keeping parsing if True    
        next_page = response.xpath('(//a[contains(., "Next")])[1]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)
```

It selects only full customer reviews without duplicate and saves them in [Scrapy Items](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#).
Note: instead of `HtmlXPathSelector` you can use more convenient shortcut `response`. Also, I change deprecated `scrapy.BaseSpider` to `scrapy.Spider`.

For saving reviews to a csv format you can simply use Scrapy [Feed exports](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#storing-the-scraped-data) and type in console `scrapy crawl webmd -o reviews.csv`.

Comment: Glad I can help. Also, you better change deprecated `scrapy.BaseSpider` to `scrapy.Spider`. And for saving scraped reviews you can use [Scrapy Items](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html).

Comment: Can you help me with saving the reviews in a .csv file?? each comment in different cell.

Comment: Is there any way to limit the number of reviews to be scraped?

Comment: Page contains 153 reviews and shows 5 reviews per page. What numbers do you need from 153?

Comment: I want just 100 reviews in total

Comment: You can see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748061/how-to-stop-scrapy-spider-after-certain-number-of-requests) from similar question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sets` to get unique comments. I hope you know that the selector returns the result as a `list` so if you use sets then you ll get only unique results. So

```
def parse(self,response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles = hxs.select("//p")
    title = set(titles.select("//p[contains(@class, 'comment')and contains(@style, 'display:none')]/text()").extract())
    print (title) #this will have only unique results.
```