# How to pass arguments when using Crawler Runner in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, scrapy, web-crawler

I've read the Official Document of `scrapy -1.0.4` about how to run multiple spiders programmatically.It supplies a way to do this by `Crawler Runner`, so I use this in my Flask App.But there is a problem that I want to pass an argument to the `Crawler` to be part of the `Start Urls`. I don't know how to do this.
Here is my Flask App code:

```
app.route('/search_process', methods=['GET'])
def search():
    configure_logging()
    runner = CrawlerRunner()
    runner.crawl(EPGDspider)
    # runner.crawl(GDSpider)
    d = runner.join()
    d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())

    reactor.run()
    return redirect(url_for('details'))
```

Here is my spiders code:

```
__author__ = 'Rabbit'
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy import Item, Field

class EPGD(Item):

    genID = Field()
    genID_url = Field()
    taxID = Field()
    taxID_url = Field()
    familyID = Field()
    familyID_url = Field()
    chromosome = Field()
    symbol = Field()
    description = Field()

class EPGDspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "EPGD"
    allowed_domains = ["epgd.biosino.org"]
    term = "man"
    start_urls = ["http://epgd.biosino.org/EPGD/search/textsearch.jsp?textquery="+term+"&submit=Feeling+Lucky"]
    MONGODB_DB = name + "_" + term
    MONGODB_COLLECTION = name + "_" + term

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//tr[@class="odd"]|//tr[@class="even"]')
        url_list = []
        base_url = "http://epgd.biosino.org/EPGD"

        for site in sites:
            item = EPGD()
            item['genID'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[1]/a/text()').extract())
            item['genID_url'] = base_url+map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[1]/a/@href').extract())[0][2:]
            item['taxID'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[2]/a/text()').extract())
            item['taxID_url'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[2]/a/@href').extract())
            item['familyID'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[3]/a/text()').extract())
            item['familyID_url'] = base_url+map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[3]/a/@href').extract())[0][2:]
            item['chromosome'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[4]/text()').extract())
            item['symbol'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[5]/text()').extract())
            item['description'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('td[6]/text()').extract())
            yield item

        sel_tmp = Selector(response)
        link = sel_tmp.xpath('//span[@id="quickPage"]')

        for site in link:
            url_list.append(site.xpath('a/@href').extract())

        for i in range(len(url_list[0])):
            if cmp(url_list[0][i], "#") == 0:
                if i+1 < len(url_list[0]):
                    print url_list[0][i+1]
                    actual_url = "http://epgd.biosino.org/EPGD/search/"+ url_list[0][i+1]
                    yield Request(actual_url, callback=self.parse)
                    break
                else:
                    print "The index is out of range!"
```

As you can see,the `term` has been set in the code already now. I just want to pass the argument `term` from Flask App to my spiders and compose the start urls dynamically.
Its effect kind of like the situation in this question:[How to pass a user defined argument in scrapy spider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611605/how-to-pass-a-user-defined-argument-in-scrapy-spider).But all the things are done in Flask App programmatically, not by command line.
But I don't know how to do this, can someone tell me how to deal with this?

Answer (score 6):

I've solve this problem by `crawl(crawler_or_spidercls, *args, **kwargs)`, you can pass arguments by this method.
Here is my Flask App code:

```
def search():
    configure_logging()
    runner = CrawlerRunner()
    runner.crawl(EPGDspider, term="man")
    d = runner.join()
    d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())

    reactor.run()
```

And my spiders code(you can override the `_init_` method and construct your dynamic `start urls`):

```
def __init__(self, term=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EPGDspider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_urls = ['http://epgd.biosino.org/EPGD/search/textsearch.jsp?textquery=%s&submit=Feeling+Lucky' % term]
```