# Recursive call for scrapy spider

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

How to restart the same spider once its finished, so that it can fetch next list of urls to process. Since my database is too large I cant pass all the websites at once. So i need the spider should run in a loop in order to fetch 100 websites process it and again fetch 100 websites and so on. Is there a way to call the spider once it finishes processing 100 websites? Please help me for the issue as I am new to scrapy. Or is there any option of scheduling the spider to run after a specified interval of time?

In the current code, i can get the urls from the domains and store it in the database. But i need to run the spider all the time. Is there a way to run it once and it will continuously run until there is no website to process. Please help.

```
class MyItem(Item):
    url = Field()

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    con = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="user",
                          passwd="pwd", db="db")
    cur = con.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur.execute("select website from table limit 100")
    name = "first"
    urls = []
    domains = []
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = []
    row = cur.fetchone()
    while row is not None:
        p = "%s" % (row["website"])
        domains.append(p)
        start_urls = "http://www.% s" % p
        urls.append(start_urls)
        row = cur.fetchone()

    allowed_domains = domains
    start_urls = urls
    cur.close()
    con.close()
    print(start_urls)
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_url', follow=True),)
    connection = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="user",
                                 passwd="pwd", db="db")
    cursor = connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

    def parse_url(self, response):
        item = MyItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        topDomain = tldextract.extract(response.url)
        tld = topDomain.domain + '.' + topDomain.suffix
        add_url = "INSERT INTO crawl_db (url,tld,time) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
        add_url_data = (item['url'], tld, strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        self.cursor.execute(add_url, add_url_data)
        self.connection.commit()
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

what about passing the job an index indicating its order, or two values indicating the offset and limit for the sql query, check [here to use it](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm).

I assume you could use a bash script to run every job and passing those parameters, to run a scrapy job with extra parameters [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611605/how-to-pass-a-user-defined-argument-in-scrapy-spider).

Now if you want to run "something" when a job is finishing, you could use an `Extension` with the `spider_closed` [signal](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#spider-closed).

[Check this tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#writing-your-own-extension) on how to create your own extension, and execute whatever you want on the `spider_closed` method. Remember to [activate it](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#loading-activating-extensions).

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by making a new python script and calling the spider from the code as follows:

```
import os

while True:
    os.system("scrapy crawl first")
```

So it runs the spider, gets the url and process it. And again runs the process with different set of urls.

Later I will be giving the condition to end once database doesn't have any url to process.

Thnakyou