# How to pass two user-defined arguments to a scrapy spider

Tags: python, scrapy

Following [How to pass a user defined argument in scrapy spider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611605/how-to-pass-a-user-defined-argument-in-scrapy-spider), I wrote the following simple spider:

```
import scrapy

class Funda1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "funda1"
    allowed_domains = ["funda.nl"]

    def __init__(self, place='amsterdam'):
        self.start_urls = ["http://www.funda.nl/koop/%s/" % place]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

This seems to work; for example, if I run it from the command line with

```
scrapy crawl funda1 -a place=rotterdam
```

It generates a `rotterdam.html` which looks similar to http://www.funda.nl/koop/rotterdam/. I would next like to extend this so that one can specify a subpage, for instance, http://www.funda.nl/koop/rotterdam/p2/. I've tried the following:

```
import scrapy

class Funda1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "funda1"
    allowed_domains = ["funda.nl"]

    def __init__(self, place='amsterdam', page=''):
        self.start_urls = ["http://www.funda.nl/koop/%s/p%s/" % (place, page)]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

However, if I try to run this with

```
scrapy crawl funda1 -a place=rotterdam page=2
```

I get the following error:

```
crawl: error: running 'scrapy crawl' with more than one spider is no longer supported
```

I don't really understand this error message, as I'm not trying to crawl two spiders, but simply trying to pass two keyword arguments to modify the `start_urls`. How could I make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When providing multiple arguments you need to prefix `-a` for **every** argument.

The correct line for your case would be:

`scrapy crawl funda1 -a place=rotterdam -a page=2`