# Python scrapy with argparsed

Tags: python, scrapy

I have nearly 20 arguments to take from the command line for a Scrapy. My project has nearly 10 web pages to parse to get data. So, have made multiple spiders and Running multiple spiders in the same process using script example from the Scrapy doc.  like

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename='scraper.log',
        format='%(created) - f%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
        level=logging.INFO
    )
    settings = args.get_args()
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    process.crawl('Connectors')
    process.crawl("helper")
    ....

    process.start()
```

I am putting arguments in Scrapy Setting after taking args from cli using argparse library. And passed the same setting object to CrawlerProcess

```
settings = args.get_args()
process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
```

I am unable to access these arguments in my spiders. If i try to get this using

```
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
self.settings = get_project_settings()
```

I am getting a new object with all null values. I have tried using **init** method to get args but that is not working. Please redirect me to some similar project on GitHub or suggest some posts to get through this problem i have already spent so much time and have much work to do.

Comment: What is `args.get_args()`? What does it return?

Comment: @mizhgun It returns the arguments passed from the command line using argparse library. Here is project repo https://github.com/examin/C.A.J.S/tree/args

Comment: [Here's how to use arguments with scrapy...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611605/how-to-pass-a-user-defined-argument-in-scrapy-spider)

Answer (score 0):

By that `settings = args.get_args()` you are passing argparse's `Namespace` instance to `CrawlerProcess` while should pass some dict-like object instead.